# how to made a method to validate a cookie authentication? asp.net core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I've tried make a method to to validate a cookie authentication but appear this error:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8u7v0.jpg)

I've tried use this:

```
public int CookieValidation()
    {
        int answer = 0;

        
        string CookieSession = HttpContext.Session.GetString("SesionSecondApp");

        if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(CookieSession))
        {
            answer = 1;
        }
        

        return answer;
    }
}
```

I made a cookie authentication:

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddCookie(options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.Name = "SesionSecondApp";
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(7);
                options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax;

            });
```

Use this claims:

```
var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, email),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role),
        };

        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
        var props = new AuthenticationProperties();

        HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, principal, props);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the browser, cookie stores the authentication configuration that has been added in the server. `SesionSecondApp` cannot be obtained from the session here, because you did not configure session.

[image]

The correct way to get `SesionSecondApp` is this code.

```
public int CookieValidation()
    {
        int answer = 0;
        var getCookie = "";
        HttpContext.Request.Cookies.TryGetValue("SesionSecondApp", out getCookie);
        //...
        return answer;
    }
```

Result:
[image]